# Problem in using latex2wp converter

Tags: html, latex2html

I used `latex2wp` package to convert my latex codes into html document. To check whether it works well, I tried to convert simple-single line math equation-codes into html document. But my result does not work appropriately. My math codes is not converted into latex form and it remains as following

```
\begin{equation*} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \end{equation*}
```

in my html document.

How can I use solve this problem? Please lend me your hands.

Comment: You will need to say better than it does not work, where did you download the 2009 beta software Where did you download which python from. How can you show to us your pyhon is working from the command line. easy by typing the response you get from> `python -V` what is the full layout of the tex file with that one line in it. what is its filename. how are you calling it on the command line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to use latex2wp

You will have seen in the readme that you need to add your tex command

```
\begin{equation*} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \end{equation*}
```

> "writing your text between the \begin{document} and \end{document}"

**into a copy of the template** source file which is called `post-template.tex`
**lets say you call that `myfirst.tex`**  you are of course happy that such a small snippet of tex should work otherwise you would need to have test a much broader range of commands in a desktop or on-line tex distribution.

You will also have followed the instructions to place in the same folder the translation scripts
 **latex2wp.py,

 latex2wpstyle.py,

 macrosblog.tex

 along with `myfirst.tex`**

So you have those four files in a fresh folder and need to start a command prompt there

Now in the console window you run

```
python latex2wp.py myfirst.tex
```

and the file gets converted to `myfirst.html`

What could go wrong ?

First off if you got

> 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Then your installation of Python 2.7 has not been found on the system path

Alternatively you got

> python: can't open file '....': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Then you must have written one of the names incorrectly.

Lastly any other error message you need to tell us what that is.